# Comparison of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have found the following two concepts:

$\bullet$ Let $L$ be a linear operator in a Hilbert space $H$. The
operator $B$ is said to be $L$-compact if $D(L)\subset D(B)$
and for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a constant $C_{\varepsilon}>0$ such that $$\|Bf\| \leq
\varepsilon \|Lf\|+ C_{\varepsilon}\|f\|\,\,\forall f \in D(L).$$

$\bullet$ Let $L$ be a linear operator in a Hilbert space $H$. The
operator $B$ is said to be is fully subordinate
to the operator $L$ if $D(L)\subset D(B)$
and if for every sufficiently
small  $\varepsilon>0$, $$\|Bf\| \leq
\varepsilon \|Lf\|+ \phi_{\varepsilon}(f) \,\,\forall f \in D(L)$$ 
where $\phi_{\varepsilon}$ is a continuous convex functional of $x \in H$.

My question is: is there a relation between these two concepts?